# How to open .docx file(from assets) in android TextView in proper format?

Tags: android

With this code, I am able to get the text file. If I replace text file with docx file it shows data in Encoded form and I need to show the text in proper format.  Is it possible with .docx file ? or any other solution for that.

```
try {
    InputStream is=getActivity().getAssets().open("getting_started.txt");
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();

    // Convert the buffer into a string.
    String text = new String(buffer);

    // Finally stick the string into the text view.
    tv_help_text.setText(text);

    } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697784/displaying-a-ms-word-file-in-viewsay-textview-in-android

Comment: I want to do this without any library @sasikumar

Comment: @priyankakataria,Did you find solution for this?